# Writing a string with comma in one column of CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I use the following line to write some information to a CSV file which is comma delimited.

```
f = open(output_file, 'w', newline='')
wr = csv.writer(f)
...
f.write(str(n) + "," + str(key) + "\n" )
```

Problem is that `key` is a string which may contain ',' and this causes the final CSV file to have more than 2 columns, while I want to write the whole `key` as a single column.

I know that `wr.writerow([key])` writes the entire key in one column, but I would like to do the same with `write()`. Any idea to fix that?

Comment: Don't do this. The very point of using `csv.writer()` is that it will do this type of escaping for you. Stick with it. (Or, if `wr` methods aren't working for you, you could specify why in your question.)

Comment: So with that I am not able to have a two column csv file. Is that what you are saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write()` is a method associated with an open file object.
`writerow()` is a method associated with a csvwriter object.

While your question indicates that you want the outcome to be generated by the `write()` function, it is not clear why you feel that you need to use the `f.write()` method to do this task. What you are attempting to do is most often handled by the `csv.writer()` I will provide some guidance on how to accomplish the outcome using `writerow()` just in case it helps you to achieve what seems to be the desired end goal.

```
import csv

n1 = 'n'
key1 = 'alpha_key,beta_key'

n2 = 42
key2 = 'no_comma_in_this_key'
```

This creates a filehandle that points toward an open file available for writing on the disk.

```
f = open('myfile.csv', 'w')
```

This creates a writer object that can use that file (f) behind the scenes to write lines to the file.

```
wr = csv.writer(f)
```

For simplicity, gonna create elements that fit into a row as a pair of strings in a list.

```
row = [str(n1), str(key1)]
```

Gonna use the csv writer's innate ability to create rows (with the appropriate quote characters to encapsulate the errant comma).

```
wr.writerow(row)
```

We can duplicate those steps with the second set of data to show how it works with keys that don't contain commas.

```
row = [str(n2), str(key2)]
wr.writerow(row)
```

When we are done with the file we should close() it, so that any data in the buffer will write to disk (NOTE: a with context manager is better, but for simplicity, going with this approach).

```
f.close()
```

The output looks like this and shows how the csv specification handles columns that might contain a comma in them by putting quotes around columns values that have a nested comma.

```
n,"alpha_key,beta_key"
42,no_comma_in_this_key
```

Altogether, the code looks like this:

```
import csv

n1 = 'n'
key1 = 'alpha_key,beta_key'

n2 = 42
key2 = 'no_comma_in_this_key'

f = open('myfile.csv', 'w')
wr = csv.writer(f)

row = [str(n1), str(key1)]
wr.writerow(row)

row = [str(n2), str(key2)]
wr.writerow(row)

f.close()
```